# Merge or redefine Kavanah tags?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags, tag-synonyms

Should we merge or redefine the "kavana" tags?

The tags in question are:
[kavana-concentration](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kavana-concentration)
[kavana-intent](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/kavana-intent/info)

This question stems from [this chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11861137#11861137).

Answer (score 1):

These have—or *should* have—different meanings; though a disambiguating word in the Hebrew would be helpful. The tag wiki for [kavana-intent](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kavana-intent) suggests “miskavein-intent”; perhaps “miskavein-intentional-actions” might be better. And some questions are certainly mis-tagged. But tag unification would conflate two usefully-separate concepts.